# How to show math symbols like theta

Tags: c++, qcustomplot

I'm trying to find a way to show math symbols such as \theta, \phi, \dot{\theta}, ..., etc. I couldn't find a way to show these letters in my plot. Does `qcustomplot` support math symbols? I've tried the following line but very few letters show up but the rest doesn't.

`ui->customPlot1->graph(0)->setName(QString("\u0024"));`

Comment: You need to create a QString properly. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromUtf8 http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromUtf16

Comment: The correct name for these symbols is greek. Greek symbols are available in some encodings. UTF8 is one of them. As n.m. noticed you just need to properly create a QString from unicode string.

Comment: @teivaz, I used theta as an example. Not all math symbols are Greek.

Comment: @CroCo If you're looking for analogue of LaTex than it seems that there is no support for it right now.

Comment: @CroCo Does your font support those symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Qt GUI in Windows 7, the following line worked

```
 title->setText(QString::fromWCharArray(L"\u03B8\u2081(t) vs \u03B8\u2081\u1d48(t)"));
```

The result is

[image]

where `\u03B8` is `\theta`, `\u2081` is subscript one, and `\u1d48` is subscript d. For the rest of charaters, see [this link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a.htm).

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is:

```
ui->customPlot1->graph(0)->setName(QString::fromUtf8("\u03B8"));
```

This for example will give you the small letter theta. Use [UTF-8 Encoding Table and Unicode Characters](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=768) to get your desired letters code.

Comment: This is exactly what I've done but didn't work. Your code shows me a question mark in my plot.

Comment: @CroCo If you can post more from your code and maybe some more information about that question mark so I will be able to look for the reason. I am currently also working on qcustomplot code and I just tried this on my plot and it worked.

Comment: @CroCo what are your OS and compiler?

Comment: @n.m. Windows 7 and Qt.

Comment: Windows doesn't particularly like utf8, you may have to type each individual byte in the `\xPQ` notation. Or try `fromUtf16` and a wide string.